# What's the most efficient way of declaring a multidimensional array of mixed types?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, vector

I'm creating a class to assist in creating excel files. I'm thinking of the various ways I could store the worksheet data in memory before computing the final output. Ideally, I'd like to do something like `std::string myArray["Sheet1"][3][7] = "this is the value of row 3 column 7 in worksheet Sheet1"` but that doesn't seem possible in C++... or is it?

Is there any easy way of going about this or am I going to have to create a multidimensional vector and have a separate array with corresponding indexes for determining the sheet name? I.E.,

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > > Worksheet;
std::vector<std::string> WorksheetNames;
// whenever I create a new worksheet...
WorksheetNames[7] = "Sheet1";
// and then to reference that worksheets' data...
Worksheet[7][1][1] = "value of row 1 column 1";
```

---

```
class ExcelSheet {
    string Code, Worksheet, Style; // temp vars for data manipulation
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > > Worksheet;

public:
    ExcelSheet();
    ExcelSheet(int,int);
    ~ExcelSheet();
    void Create();
    void Destroy();
    bool SetEntryValue(std::string szWorksheet, int nColumn, int nRow);
    bool SetEntryStyle(std::string szWorksheet, int nColumn, int nRow);
};
```

Comment: Classy as your response may be, "struct" is of no value to me out of context / absent any explanation. Would you care to elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a `std::unordered_map<string, ExcelSheet*>` would be better than storing a vector of strings to refer to your worksheet.

In this way you can access a single sheet in constant time and don't have to worry about many things. Of course this won't have a continuous layout in memory but I guess you don't need it. You can still store the name in the specific sheet (and store them in a `std::vector` if you need) and use the map as a pairing used to access specific sheets by name.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for (nested) [associative containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Something like this should get you started:

```
typedef std::map< unsigned, std::string > columns;
typedef std::map< unsigned, columns > rows;
typedef std::map< std::string, rows > sheets;

sheets my_sheets;
my_sheets["Sheet1"][3][7] = "hello";
```